# remote_directory resource in a provider trying to resolve path in wrapper cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I have a provider in my base cookbook, within which I am using the [`remote_directory`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_directory.html) resource to copy a bunch of directories & files from `files/default/my_stuff`, located in the base cookbook along with the provider.

When I call that provider from another cookbook, Chef is trying to find `files/default/my_stuff` in the wrapper cookbook, is that the desired behaviour or a bug?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using `remote_directory` to deploy files from the cookbook? Maybe you're using `cookbook_file`? Btw: You can omit the `default/` subdir since couple of chef versions.

Comment: Positive. Initially it looked strange having to set the cookbook parameter to the same cookbook the provider is written in, but on reflection it makes sense that the Provider is executed from the context of the cookbook that calls it.

Comment: Great. Any clarification regarding the `cookbook_file` vs. `remote_directory` (`remote_file`) issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the source cookbook for [`cookbook_file`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_cookbook_file.html)/`template` resources using the `cookbook` parameter:

```rb
cookbook_file 'name' do
  cookbook "some_cookbook"
end
```

This will look in the `files/` folder of the `some_cookbook`cookbook, instead of the cookbook, where the resource is defined.

EDIT: Yes, that's no bug.

Comment: I had previously tried setting the cookbook property, must have been a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: I guess the point of my question is that a Provider is executed from the cookbook that wraps it, so it's intentional behaviour

Comment: More specifically `cookbook_name` comes from the actual recipe that is at the top of the chain. So a resource in a resource in a resource, it goes all the way up by default.